# Winbase.h doesn't support in creating DLL file

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I would like to create a project use to call c++ method using c#. So, I need to create a dll file for all of my c++ function. But when i get an error in y sqlite source code such as "AreFileApisASNSI undeclared identifier". So, i import winbase.h which is  part of the mingw-w64 runtime package to my visual studio 2012 express DLL project. After import the file, I get many errors such as below:-

error c4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default - int

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '_stdcall'

error c1003 error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation

error c2061: syntax error: identifier ' WINBOOL'

error c2086: 'int_CRT_INLINE' : redefinition

error c2143: syntax error: missing ';' before ''

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'LONGLONG'

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'PVOID'

any solution for those error? please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363781.aspx) for the function has this header requirement:

> WinBase.h (include Windows.h)

This is telling you that the function is declared in `WinBase.h`, but that you should include `Windows.h` which in turn will include `WinBase.h`. So, you need to change your include to

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

I also wonder why you are talking about mingw considering that your compiler is MSVC. That compiler ships with a comprehensive Windows SDK. Why would you be using an SDK from mingw?

Comment: I have include windows.h but it is still get the same error. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: You fix it by doing what I said. Step 1: remove `#include <WinBase.h>`. Step 2: add `#include <Windows.h>`.

Comment: Thank you. But I follow exactly your step but it still get the same error.

Comment: Not so here. I start with an empty project which compiles fine. I add an include of WinBase.h and see the errors you report. I then switch to an include of Windows.h and the errors clear. So, I can reproduce your fault, and the fix works. You presumably have some other include of WinBase.h somewhere else, or some other error. Perhaps you could add an SSCCE to the question.

Comment: Anyway, I did my trials using the SDK that comes with VS Express. What has mingw got to do with this?